# Extract a match in a row and take everything until a comma or take it if it is the end ot the string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a dataset. In the column 'Tags' I want to extract from each row all the content that has the word player. I could repeat or be alone in the same cell. Something like this:

'view_snapshot_hi:hab,like_hi:hab,view_snapshot_foinbra,completed_profile,view_page_investors_landing,view_foinbra_inv_step1,view_foinbra_inv_step2,view_foinbra_inv_step3,view_snapshot_acium,**player**,view_acium_inv_step1,view_acium_inv_step2,view_acium_inv_step3,**player_acium-ronda-2_r1**,view_foinbra_rinv_step1,view_page_makers_landing'

expected output:
'player,player_acium-ronda-2_r1'

And I need both.

```
df["Tags"] = df["Tags"].str.ectract(r'*player'*,?\s*')
```

I tried this but it´s not working.

Comment: `df["Tags"] = df["Tags"].str.extract(r'(player[^,]*)', expand=False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Series.str.extract` keeping in mind that the pattern should contain a capturing group embracing the part you need to extract.

The pattern you need is `player[^,]*`:

```py
df["Tags"] = df["Tags"].str.extract(r'(player[^,]*)', expand=False)
```

The `expand=False` returns a Series/Index rather than a dataframe.

Note that `Series.str.extract` finds and fetches the first match only. To get all matches use either of the two solutions below with `Series.str.findall`:

```py
df["Tags"] = df["Tags"].str.findall(r'player[^,]*', expand=False)
df["Tags"] = df["Tags"].str.findall(r'player[^,]*', expand=False).str.join(", ")
```

Comment: I tried your solution but, I´m jus geting the first match. 
expected output: 'player,player_acium-ronda-2_r1'
Getting : 'player'

Comment: @DiegoGonzálezCastellanos Sure, I just used the method you used in your question. Use the `Series.str.findall` to get all matches.

Answer (score 0):

This simple list also gives what you want

```
words_with_players = [item for item in your_str.split(',') if 'player' in item]
players = ','.join(words_with_players)
```